# Pronunciation of 空室

Tags: word-choice, pronunciation, readings

I have seen 空室 listed as having both the pronunciation くうしつ and あきしつ (both alone and in the phrase 空室あり). Which of these readings is more appropriate for everyday use? Is there a difference in nuance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my experience it's usually read **くうしつ**. And all IMEs I have (on Windows and Android) refuses to convert あきしつ to 空室.

空き室 is read あきしつ, but this word is less common.